# How to enable usage of @CollectionCacheable with Spring Boot v2.0.9.RELEASE and few other dependencies (aop, cache, micrometer etc.)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching

I would like to use @CollectionCacheable (or something similar if available) on a custom spring boot 2.0.9 project, but I cannot make application to start.

The @CollectionCacheable homepage: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.qaware.tools.collection-cacheable-for-spring/collection-cacheable-for-spring-starter/1.2.0

POM relevant content:

```
    ...
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>
        </properties>
<dependencies>
    ...
            
            <!-- Micormeter core dependecy  -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Micrometer Prometheus registry  -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
        <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.qaware.tools.collection-cacheable-for-spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>collection-cacheable-for-spring-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
<dependencies>
```

The error:

```
2021-12-07 11:53:45.661  WARN 119220 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistryPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/MetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cache/annotation/ProxyCachingConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.interceptor.BeanFactoryCacheOperationSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'cacheAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cache/annotation/ProxyCachingConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.configure(Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Ljava/util/function/Supplier;)V
2021-12-07 11:53:45.665 ERROR 119220 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.configure(Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Ljava/util/function/Supplier;)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/[user]/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.0.13.RELEASE/spring-context-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheInterceptor.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/[user]/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.0.13.RELEASE/spring-context-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor
```

Comment: If you check the library you are using that is for Spring BOot 2.5 you are on 2.0 which isn't compatible, hence the error. So either find a compatible version or upgrade Spring Boot.

Comment: The question is open to suggestions (maybe something similar to @CollectionCacheable but compatible with older versions? or some minor guidance to implement for 2.0?). Upgrade is not an option for spring boot (or spring) at this point. Anyway, the problem itself is about caching elements while using collections (as for spring data, it seems not right to cache findByIds in different cache in regards to findById :/).

Comment: As stated find an older version of that library that **is** compatible. Or don't use it as the lowest version starts with Spring Boot 2.4. If you want to use newer technologies you will need to upgrade.